# Export topology tables to txt files using ArcObjects, generating directed graph, and finding intersections

Tags: arcobjects, polygon, geometry, spatial-database, vba

I want to export topology tables to  text files:

```
for points:   
1  id  x   y

for lines:
line id   fompoint.x  from point.y  topoint.x  topoint.y

for polygons:
id   line id 1, line id 2...

2   arc list
3   node list
```

Using ArcObjects VBA.